# Why does configuration.nix compile while nix-shell uses a prebuilt binary?

Tags: configuration, wsl-2, nixos

I'm using NixOS as the distro on WSL (via the excellent setup provided by Trundle: https://github.com/Trundle/NixOS-WSL) and I'd like to install the racket package. If I run `nix-shell -p racket`, it dutifully downloads (or uses the previously downloaded) the pre-built binary and I can use it just fine. But if I add `racket` to the `environment.systemPackages` list in configuration.nix and try to `nixos-rebuild test`, it starts trying to build things from source. It fails when it gets to gtk (presumably because WSL2 doesn't yet support graphical applications).

Why the difference in behavior? Is there a way I can convince NixOS to use the pre-built racket when filling out the systemPackages? Happy to post my configuration.nix if it would help the diagnosis, though it's really not much of a departure from Trundle's.

Comment: Did you define any overlays? Does your user use the same channel profiles as the `root` user? You can check the latter with `echo $NIX_PATH` and following any symlinks.

Comment: I have not defined any overlays. My NIX_PATH is `nixpkgs=/nix/var/nix/profiles/per-user/root/channels/nixos:nixos-config=/etc/nixos/configuration.nix:/
nix/var/nix/profiles/per-user/root/channels` and I think this is the same as for the root user.

Comment: Could you run `nix show-config | grep -E 'subst|keys'`? It should have `https://cache.nixos.org` in `substituters` and `cache.nixos.org-1:6NCHdD59X431o0gWypbMrAURkbJ16ZPMQFGspcDShjY=` in `trusted-public-keys`

Comment: Yes. It has both of these:

```
[nixos@nixos:/mnt/c/Users/Lucas]$ nix show-config | grep -E 'subst|keys'
builders-use-substitutes = false
extra-substituters =
substitute = true
substituters = https://cache.nixos.org/
trusted-public-keys = cache.nixos.org-1:6NCHdD59X431o0gWypbMrAURkbJ16ZPMQFGspcDShjY=
trusted-substituters =
```